# how json to reference data from another json

Tags: python, json

I have the following json data.

users:

```
[
    {
        "group_ids": [
            "group_1"
        ],
        "user_id": "U_1",
        "name": "kite"
    },
    {
        "group_ids": [
            "group_1",
            "group_2"
        ],
        "user_id": "U_2",
        "name": "mike"
    },
    {
        "group_ids": [
            "group_1",
            "group_3"
        ],
        "user_id": "U_3",
        "name": "an"
    },
    {
        "group_ids": [
            "group_3"
        ],
        "user_id": "U_4",
        "name": "joe"
    }
]
```

groups:

```
{
    "group_1": {
        "label": "sre",
        "group_type": "freelance"
    },
    "group_2": {
        "label": "dev",
        "group_type": "staff"
    },
    "group_3": {
        "label": "qa",
        "group_type": "member"
    },
    "group_4": {
        "label": "ops",
        "group_type": "staff"
    }
}
```

I want to get the following output with the keys in order when given user id `U_2`.
Any pseudo code or hints will be good.

```
    {
        "groups": [
            {"label": "sre", "group_type": "freelance"},
            {"label": "dev", "group_type": "staff"}
        ],
        "user_id": "U_2",
        "name": "mike"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep dict keys in order, you'll have to use the standard [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class.

In the snippet below, I assume you have two JSON files `users.json` and `groups.json`.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
from pathlib import Path


# Load data from JSON files
users = json.loads(Path("users.json").read_text())
groups = json.loads(Path("groups.json").read_text())

# Index users by their ID
users = {user["user_id"]: user for user in users}


def get_groups(user_id):
    # Get the required user representation
    user = users[user_id].copy()
    # Get list of its group IDs and remove it from its representation
    group_ids = user.pop("group_ids")
    # Add group representation for each group
    user["groups"] = [groups[group_id] for group_id in group_ids]
    # Convert user to OrderedDict to ensure keys are sorted
    keys = "groups", "user_id", "name"
    user = OrderedDict([(key, user[key]) for key in keys])
    # Done!
    return user
```

The result of `get_groups("U_2")` is then:

```py
>>> get_groups("U_2")
OrderedDict([('groups', [{'label': 'sre', 'group_type': 'freelance'}, {'label': 'dev', 'group_type': 'staff'}]), ('user_id', 'U_2'), ('name', 'mike')])
```

Finally, the standard `json.dump` and `json.dumps` to convert to JSON string will respect the order of keys when you pass an `OrderedDict` to them.

```py
>>> print(json.dumps(get_groups("U_2"), indent=4))
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "label": "sre",
            "group_type": "freelance"
        },
        {
            "label": "dev",
            "group_type": "staff"
        }
    ],
    "user_id": "U_2",
    "name": "mike"
}
```

Comment: no need to use pandas.but I want to keep the keys in orders(groups, user_id,name).

Comment: Interesting! You should probably edit your question - remove the reference to `pandas` and add your ordering requirements.

Comment: @user12951309 I've edited the answer with a solution to keep keys in a fixed order. Let me know if it helps!